# how I do the ng-repeat of json file hosted on the external url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Lets say my url is http://www.example.com/apptest/app/index.php/json/getSingleMenuItemReviews?id=94

and the json file is on this Url is:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`id`  AS `id` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`order`  AS `order` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`status`  AS `status` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`reviewcomment`  AS `reviewcomment` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`json`  AS `json` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`  AS `menuitemid` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menutypeid`  AS `menutypeid` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`user`  AS `user` ,  `webapp_menuitems`.`name`  AS `menuitemname` ,  `webapp_menuitems`.`image`  AS `menuitemimage` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`timestamp`  AS `timestamp` ,  `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`rate`  AS `rate` ,  1  \n\t\tFROM `webapp_menuitem_reviews` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `webapp_menuitems` ON `webapp_menuitems`.`id`=`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`  WHERE `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`status`=1 AND `webapp_menuitems`.`status`=1 AND `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`='94' AND (  1 )      ORDER BY  `order` DESC,  1  LIMIT 0,20",
  "queryresult": [{
    "id": "1",
    "order": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "reviewcomment": "22222",
    "json": "0",
    "menuitemid": "94",
    "menutypeid": "13",
    "user": "jose",
    "menuitemname": "test food",
    "menuitemimage": "super-foods-400x400.jpg",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-19 02:06:14",
    "rate": "2"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "order": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "reviewcomment": "Hhhgh",
    "json": "0",
    "menuitemid": "94",
    "menutypeid": "13",
    "user": "jose",
    "menuitemname": "test food",
    "menuitemimage": "super-foods-400x400.jpg",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-19 03:27:09",
    "rate": "4"
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "order": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "reviewcomment": "Hhhgh",
    "json": "0",
    "menuitemid": "94",
    "menutypeid": "13",
    "user": "jose",
    "menuitemname": "test food",
    "menuitemimage": "super-foods-400x400.jpg",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-19 03:27:10",
    "rate": "4"
  }, {
    "id": "8",
    "order": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "reviewcomment": "mremajoel",
    "json": "0",
    "menuitemid": "94",
    "menutypeid": "13",
    "user": "jose",
    "menuitemname": "test food",
    "menuitemimage": "super-foods-400x400.jpg",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-19 16:10:45",
    "rate": "5"
  }],
  "totalvalues": 4,
  "pageno": 1,
  "lastpage": 1,
  "elements": [{
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`id`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "ID",
    "alias": "id"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`order`",
    "sort": "DESC",
    "header": "Order",
    "alias": "order"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`status`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "Status",
    "alias": "status"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`reviewcomment`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "reviewcomment",
    "alias": "reviewcomment"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`json`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "Json",
    "alias": "json"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "menuitemid",
    "alias": "menuitemid"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menutypeid`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "menutypeid",
    "alias": "menutypeid"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`user`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "user",
    "alias": "user"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitems`.`name`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "name",
    "alias": "menuitemname"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitems`.`image`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "image",
    "alias": "menuitemimage"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`timestamp`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "timestamp",
    "alias": "timestamp"
  }, {
    "field": "`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`rate`",
    "sort": "1",
    "header": "Rate",
    "alias": "rate"
  }],
  "from": "\n\t\tFROM `webapp_menuitem_reviews` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `webapp_menuitems` ON `webapp_menuitems`.`id`=`webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`",
  "where": "WHERE `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`status`=1 AND `webapp_menuitems`.`status`=1 AND `webapp_menuitem_reviews`.`menuitemid`='94'",
  "group": "",
  "having": "",
  "search": false,
  "startingfrom": 0,
  "maxlength": 20,
  "options": []
}
```

how can I get all the data to display on the list item.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `$http` to get data and assign response to your model...see docs

Comment: Strongly suggest you study some basic angular tutorials https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. Also read [ask]. This question is far too broad and this isn't a tutorial service

Answer (score 0):

You would generally use Angulars $http service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http in a controller or factory and then bind the JSON data to $scope in your controller https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

In the html template you bind( present ) the JSON data using ng-bind https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind.

I found http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GtaQ0oMGIl/ helpful to learn the basics of angular.